# Probability of successful reception in VEINS

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, 802.11p

I am doing research around evaluation routing protocols in Veins 4.4 and was wondering how can I find the probability of successful reception in VEINS without major modifications to the code to trace the messages.

Assuming we cannot have ACK as usual due to ACK explosion and all the 802.11p specifics - what is the best approach without changing code too much?

Did all the papers showing probability of successful reception in their simulation results implement it themselves?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to model a mechanism that estimates this probability of success? Or do you want to model a mechanism and then estimate its probability of success?

Comment: Thank you. I have somewhat of a model similar to weighted-p and trying to estimate its probability of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a model and want to estimate its probability of successful packet transmission, I would recommend to count (a) the number of attempted transmissions in a simulation and (b) the number of successful transmissions. The ratio of successful transmissions in a given simulation can then be calculated as the fraction of b/a. Given enough simulations, the typical probability of success can be calculated, along with statistical measures of precision of the prediction.

Comment: Thank you, but the probability of a successful transmission would not be the same as the probability of successful reception or is that how the reception is estimated as well?

Comment: It is entirely up to you how you want to define that a transmission was (a) attempted and (b) successful. For example, you could define (a) as "a vehicles noticed a broadcast taking place" and (b) as "a vehicle successfully received a broadcast"